# React SSR React Router Dom Switch, Route, Link "Invariant Failed"

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering

I beleive the proper discription of this issue is explained [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6789#issuecomment-502490351) by timdorr. I tried exporting App.js from the bundle but get window undefined errors. SO still stuck

SSR/Client React Router Dom "Switch" breaks for me with a "Invariant Failed". I believe it says it has something to do with Switch not been allowed outside "Router", which it is inside.

The minimal project link is below, that may be easier way look at the project. I have listed the main files below

1: SERVER SIDE RENDER ENDPOINT

```
// EXPRESS ROUTER
const express = require("express");
const aRouter = express.Router();

// REACT UTILITIES
import React from "react";
import { renderToNodeStream } from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import Loadable from "react-loadable";

// REDUX UTILITIES
import { init } from "../src/module/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

// CUSTOM COMPONENTS
import App from "../src/App";

// UTILITIES
import fs from "fs-extra";
import renderUtils from "../utils/renderUtils";

// ASSETS
import { initState } from "../assets/store/init";

aRouter.get(["/", "/home"], async function (req, res) {

  console.log("RENDER HOME");

  try {

    // INITIAL WRITE TO CLIENT - START HEAD
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    res.write("<html style='scrollbar-width: none;'>");

    let headHTML = await fs.readFile("./public/head.html", "utf-8");
    let scriptsHTML = await fs.readFile("./public/scripts.html", "utf-8");

    res.write(headHTML);
    res.write("<body>");
    res.write(`<div id = "app-container">`);

    // INITALISING STATE
    var initialState = initState();
    initialState.article.articles = {
      "abcde": {
        title: "My First Article",
        body: "This is my first article"
      },
      "fghij": {
        title: "My Second Article",
        body: "This is my second article"
      },
      "klmno": {
        title: "My Third Article",
        body: "This is my third article"
      }
    };
    initialState.article.fetched = true;
    initialState.ui.user = { type: "" };
    initialState.ui.global = {
      team: "Arsenal",
      teamID: 19
    };

    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [req.originalUrl] });
    const store = init(history, initialState);
    
    // THE ISSUE SEEMS TO BE TO DO WITH THIS SERVER SIDE STATIC BROWSER AND THE CLIENT BORWSER ROUTER
    const stream = renderToNodeStream(
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <StaticRouter history = {history} location = {req.originalUrl} context = {{}}>
          <App />
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    stream.pipe(res, { end: false });
    stream.on("end", renderUtils.onRenderEnd.bind(this, res, store, scriptsHTML));

  } catch (err) { renderUtils.onRenderError.bind(this, res, "RENDER HOME ERROR", err.message); }

});

var self = (module.exports = aRouter);
```

2: CLIENT INDEX

```
// REACT
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Loadable from "react-loadable";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

// REDUX
import { init } from "./module/store";

// CREATE STORE
let history = createMemoryHistory();
let store = init(history, window.INITIAL_STATE);

// MAIN APP COMPONENT
import App from "./App";

// MOUNTED STYLES
import "./style/client/index.scss";

const renderApp = () => {
  ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <BrowserRouter history = {history}>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("app-container")
  );
};

store.subscribe(() => renderApp());
```

3: APP - CLIENT

```
// REACT
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// REDUX STORE
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getName, getAge, getPosition } from "./module/user/userReducer";
import { getUIElement, setUIElement } from "./module/uiReducer";

// IMPORT CUSTOM COMPONENTS
import Routes from "./Routes";

class App extends PureComponent {

  componentDidMount = () => this.props.setUI("user", "type", "admin");

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className = "app">
        <span>My App</span>
        <span>Name : {this.props.name}</span>
        <span>Age : {this.props.age}</span>
        <span>Position : {this.props.position}</span>
        <span>Team : {this.props.team}</span>
        <span>Team ID : {this.props.teamID}</span>
        <span>Type : {this.props.type}</span>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path = "/" component = {MyLocation} />
            <Route path = "/contact" render = {() => (<MyLocation location = "Contact" />)} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

};

App.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  age: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  position: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  team: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  teamID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  setUI: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: getName(state),
  age: getAge(state),
  position: getPosition(state),
  team: getUIElement(state, "global", "team"),
  teamID: getUIElement(state, "global", "teamID"),
  type: getUIElement(state, "user", "type")
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setUI: (component, element, value) => dispatch(setUIElement({ component, element, value }))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

The full minimal react app [here](https://github.com/GaddMaster/gaddbox?fbclid=IwAR0st1_ZWNVJ-Z86m8dFZIPNTIs5XetU1b7jd-t7_IbCI08Jvss0KDzVuIg)

It just breaks when I add the Switch and Routes. The Switch "IS INSIDE" the Browser Router. I have read articles which explain to send the same React Router Dom to the client, but I tried them explanations and they dont work for me.

To run the project simply run "yarn",  "npm run build" and "npm start". The app has just one page with some filler text

Issue : Breaks at Switch
Required: Work at Switch
Tried: Explantions that explain to bring same instance of react-router-dom to client from server and use webpack alies etc.

### Timdorr (Shared at start of question) explains this.

### There is a new React.createContext API that we use in 5.0 to replace the legacy context usage. This involves creating a "context" pair, a set of Provider and Consumer components. We create that in a singleton module that is imported into Router and Link directly. In this new API, you have to use the exact same instance. Two separately-created contexts will never match up and won't be visible to each other.

Whats also funny is this works live on Heroku "production", but doesnt work locally "production". Im thinking heroku have some fallback code catching it.

Any help be great;

Daniel

Comment: Maybe try to remove node_modules folder and update all / reinstall all dependencies, then make sure you're using the exact version of BrowserRouter, Switch, and Route in all of the files. And also, In the APP-CLIENT file you're actually using switch outside of the browserRouter, try to make it like this :`<BrowserRouter> <Switch> ...`, meaning make switch a direct child of the router. I am not saying it will solve the problem, but trying would not hurt :)

Comment: Hi. I am not using Switch outside  BrowserRouter btw. This doesn't work either, but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of playing around I discovered the issue stemmed from

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export default withRouter(Component);
```

I think **withRouter** doesn't exists anymore on this new version and as as to why it worked with Heroku is a mystery. I think Heroku has great version controlling and debugging/handling.

I started using the hook **useHistory** instead and converted my classic components to function component with hooks and all is well now

Daniel